# Should I rename my .html in .php when using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have an `index.html` page, in which I have a button that runs php code through Javascript, using `XMLHttpRequest`.

The php code just reads `index.html` and make computations, but it does not inject php code.

Since the code is not working, I am wondering if I have to rename my file `index.html` to `index.php`. Should I do it?

Comment: the file extension is not important.. check the browsers error console

Comment: This is an X/Y problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding to [Jesse's answer](/a/47247722):

> You only have to rename the page to `.php` if there is PHP code on that page that needs to be executed. If that is not the case, you can leave it as `.html`.

Also, make sure you don't have caching enabled for `.html` files, as generally, being a static file, AJAX tends to get the cached version of it. You can disable AJAX caching by two ways:

**Using XHR's caching:**

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
```

Or, appending a query string:

```
xhr.open('GET', 'file.html?cachebuster=' + new Date().getTime());
```

Answer (score 3):

You only have to rename the page to `.php` if there is PHP code on that page that needs to be executed. If that is not the case, you can leave it as `.html`.

Comment: I referred to your answer.